# Can't connect to mysql, despite multiple password reset attempts

Tags: mysql, cmd, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a backend node server on Windows. I'm using MySQL8.0, and since the beginning, my db root has had a password set. In the middle of working, MySQL Workbench kicked me out of my database connection and I haven't been able to connect since, either on Workbench or in command line. I keep getting the following error:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 
127.0.0.1:3306: 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

***Things I've attempted:***

> Intentionally entering in wrong/different password

**RESULT**: Before I started fiddling with everything, I got an error related to invalid credentials (ie. not the same as the Access denied). After I did all the following, if the server is running, same "Access denied" error. If the server is not running, "can't connect to server on 'localhost'" error.

`mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`

**RESULT**: Request for password, "Access denied."

`mysqld.exe -u root --skip-grant-tables`

**RESULT**: Multiple [Server] "Can't create test file" errors followed by [Server] "Aborting" This is the same whether the server is running or not.

`mysql_secure_installation`

**RESULT**: I'm asked for my password. If server is running, get "Access denied" error. If turned off, get "can't connect to server on 'localhost'" error.

> Attempted to reinstall mysql as a service

RESULT: I now have two mysql services: MySQL (new) and MySQL80 (original). The issue persists, no matter which is running.

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root -p
```

**RESULT**: This doesn't have errors now? Except I'm also requested for a password. Same "Access denied" error.

> Followed the instructions to reset my password listed at Mysql's website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

**RESULT**: I can finally connect! Except I open up Workbench to find all my databases missing. I realize I have MySQL service running, and not MySQL80. I switch to that. The "Access denied" error is back.

> `sc remove MySQL`
>
> Repeated instructions for resetting password

**RESULT**: Now only have MySQL80. When using mysql-init.txt to run server, I can log in on Workbench, but all my databases are missing here too. I close out, restart the service manually. Back to "Access denied" error.

My app's node server has had no issue connecting to MySQL80 when it was running, despite all this. It's using a non-root user to login.

Comment: Have you tried stopping both servers? If not try to change the port for one server and try starting that one in `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

Comment: I've unfortunately tried that as well...